# Page Navigation with PHP Sessions

Tags: php, session, navigation

I am trying to make simple navigation rules for a visitor for my website. I want to prevent visitor accessing specific pages if they have not visited other pages before.
I have this simple code on page1.php:

```
<?php 
 session_start();
 $_SESSION["currentPage"] = 1;
?>
```

And this code on my page2.php:

```
<?php
 session_start();
 if ($_SESSION["currentPage"] == 1 ) {
   $_SESSION["currentPage"] = 2;
   $_SESSION["test"] = "Hello";
 }else{ 
   $_SESSION["currentPage"] = 3;
  }
?>
```

After visiting page1.php and then page2.php and echoing out `$_SESSION["currentPage"]` and `$_SESSION["test"]` I get "`Hello`" and "`3`".

I just don't understand why the code is executed in both blocks of the if statement...I need it to stop after `$_SESSION["currentPage"]` is set to "`2`".

I am running PHP 5.3.28

Answer (score 0):

It executes

```
$_SESSION["currentPage"] = 2;
$_SESSION["test"] = "Hello";
```

When you open page2.php first time, and

```
$_SESSION["currentPage"] = 3;
```

When you refresh the page because `$_SESSION["currentPage"]` is not 1 anymore.
`$_SESSION` is persistent across request. Clear cookies to and try again.

Comment: Thanks for reply, @AlexBlex. However, this occurs when the following steps are made:
1. Clear browser cache and cookies
2. Visit page1.php
3. Visit page2.php

Comment: I doubt so. Try to reproduce it with curl: 1.`curl -v http://.../page1.php`, 2.`curl -v --cookie "...session cookie from previous response..." http://..../page2.php` and update your question with output of both commands.

Comment: ,I found out that removing line `session_cache_limiter('private_no_expire')` in my code solved the problem. For me this line was solving the problem with ERR_CACHE_MISS error when navigating back in form.